# Is it possible to print and then remove files found with a single 'find' bash command?

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to use a single 'find' command to find and print all the files named with a specific pattern. All good with that for now. But now I'm trying to delete those files without writing a second command, so I tried to use the arguments '-delete' and '-exec rm -f {} ;' but none of them actually print the files in the terminal.

So, is it actually possible to print those files and then delete them with a single find command ?

Comment: Yes it is. The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course this is possible. Use `find`'s `-print` command:

```
find ... -print -delete
```

`-print` is the implicit default action for `find`. When you explicitly specify an action like `-delete` or `-exec` the default is overwritten, so you have to explicitly specify it again. From `man find`:

> If no expression is given, the  expression  -print  is  used